# Instrumentation amplifier dealing with wire resistances

Tags: operational-amplifier, instrumentation-amplifier

[image: strong text]

Can anyone please help me in understanding the output of this amplifier? According to me it is coming as 
(E1-E2)(1+(Rw/R)).

I am more curious about knowing wheather Rw will come in the output equation or not, and if not how will it get eliminated.

Comment: Why not use a simulator?

Comment: How do you know that is an inst. amp? Instrumentation amplifiers normally have a single gain resistor, what you have shown looks more like a difference amplifier.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

The presence of the BJT should not put you off because it's just an emitter follower AND is contained within the feedback loop (just are all the internal transistors in the signal chain inside the op-amp).

> *According to me it is coming as (E1-E2)(1+(Rw/R)).*

Using your resistor names the gain is: -

$$\dfrac{V_O}{E1 - E2} = \dfrac{R_W + R}{R}$$

That looks to be the same as your formula.